# Vue.js - Caching AJAX call in created method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

#### Description

I have a `parent` component that shows or hides a `child` component when you click on a button.

The `child` component, when it is created, make an `AJAX` call. Each time we close the `child` and click on the `button` to open it again, `child` is re-rendered and then the `AJAX` call is made again.

#### Questions / Problems

I am wondering wether there is a way to cache the result of an `AJAX` call using `vue-js`. while keeping the `v-if`? So I don't have to query the server each time.

#### Parent component

```
<template>
    <button @click='showChild = true'></button>
    <child v-if="showChild"></child>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: '',
    data () {
      return {
          showChild: false
      }
    },
    components: {
       child
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Child Component

```
<template>
    <div>
     {{resultAJAX}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: '',
    data () {
      return {
         resultAJAX: ''
      }
    },
    created () {
        axios.get(api/getData).then((response) => {this.resultAJAX = response.data});
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [keep-alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) component.

```
<template>
    <button @click='showChild = true'></button>
    <keep-alive>
        <child v-if="showChild"></child>
    </keep-alive>
</template>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xdvYVZ?editors=1010).

Comment: What is the difference between `v-show` and `keep-alive` ? Is `v-show` a kind of `keep-alive`?

Comment: @Leo It's not quite the same. With `v-show` all that happens is a style of `display:none` is added to the component doesn't have to create/mount. With `keep-alive` and `v-if` the component is removed from the DOM (not hidden), but it is not destroyed, so the `created` lifecycle event does not fire again and its state is preserved.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I need to create a new question for that butt this specific example does not work https://jsfiddle.net/4fwphqhv/ `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined"` Have you any idea why and how to fix it ?

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290231/vue-js-keep-alive-component-error-next-tick