# Vue.js - Keep Alive Component - Error next Tick

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, keep-alive

#### Description

I'm trying to take advantage of the `keep-alive` functionality of `vue-js 2.3` so my `AJAX` call is made only once.

#### Problem

The second time I try to open the `popup` component I get this error :

> Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined"
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined

#### Steps

Click on the button to display the popup

Wait for one second

Close the popup

Click again on the button

https://jsfiddle.net/4fwphqhv/

#### Minimal reproduction example

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showDialog = true">Show Component PopUp</button>
  <keep-alive>
      <popup v-if="showDialog" :show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>
  </keep-alive>
</div>

<template id="popup">
    <el-dialog :visible.sync="show" @visible-change="updateShowDialog">{{asyncData}}</el-dialog>
</template>


Vue.component('popup', {
  template: '#popup',
  props : ['showDialog'],
  data(){
    return {
        show: this.showDialog,
      asyncData: "Loading please wait"
    }
  },
  methods: {
   updateShowDialog(isVisible) {
       if (isVisible) return false;
       this.$emit('update:showDialog', false )
   }
  },
   created:function (){
    const _this = this
    setTimeout(() => _this.asyncData = 'Async Data was loaded' , 1000)
  },
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showDialog: false,
  },
});
```

#### Real code of the popup component

```
<template>
    <el-dialog title="Order in progress" size="large" :visible.sync="show" @visible-change="updateShowLoadOrder"></el-dialog>
</template>

<script>
  let popUpData;
  export default {
    name: '',
    data () {
      return {
        ordersInProgress: [],
        show: this.showLoadOrder
      }
    },
    props: ['showLoadOrder'],
    methods: {
      updateShowLoadOrder (isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) return false;
        this.$emit('update:showLoadOrder', false)
      }
    },
    created () {
      const _this = this;
      if (!popUpData) {
        axios.get('api/mtm/apiGetOrdersInProgress').then((response) => {
          _this.ordersInProgress = popUpData = response.data;
        });
      } else {
        this.ordersInProgress = popUpData;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's definitely the element-ui dialog component. You can remove that and replace it with something else and it works fine. Something is not playing nice.

Comment: I'll post an issue on their `github` to see if they can fix it. Meanwhile, I'll just won't put the `keep-alive`

Comment: This is a workaround that will cache the data. https://jsfiddle.net/4fwphqhv/2/

Comment: Where would you define the `popupData` in a single file component? I tried to put it in `data` and  I still have the same error in my real project.

Comment: before export default, below any imports you do. Will you have more than one popup? If so, might need to modify.

Comment: It still does not work. I updated the topic by adding the real code of my `popup` element. I do not see major differences that could explain the fact it is working with your `jsfiddle` and not in my project.

Comment: you removed the keep-alive right?

Comment: It works better without it indeed! Thank you for the workaround. I hope `element-ui` will solve the issue the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So your problem here is the wrong life-cycle hook.

If you change `created` to `activated`... it should work. It did for me in your JS fiddle.

```
activated:function (){
    setTimeout(() => this.asyncData = 'Async Data was loaded' , 1000)
}
```

There are two other hooks, activated and deactivated. These are for keep-alive components, a topic that is outside the scope of this article. Suffice it to say that they allow you to detect when a component that is wrapped in a  tag is toggled on or off. You might use them to fetch data for your component or handle state changes, effectively behaving as created and beforeDestroy without the need to do a full component rebuild.

**SOURCE**: [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/)

Comment: Click "Show Component PopUp" twice. That's when the error occurs. Just changing the lifecycle event doesn't fix the problem.